# Which C stardard adopted given the GNU C compiler version?

Tags: c, gcc

Given that I know the compiler version:

```
ANSI C 5.3.0 - GNU C Compiler with options: -lm -lcrypt -O2 -pipe -ansi -DONLINE_JUDGE
```

How can I know which C standard(C89, C99, C11, C17/18) it adopted If I want to write C program that strictly follows the standard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gcc has a flag that lets you specify the version of the C standard to compile against.

- `-std=c89` for C89
- `-std=c99` for C99
- `-std=c11` for C11

The version you have probably doesn't have support for C17.

There's also:

- `-std=gnu89` for C89 with GNU extensions
- `-std=gnu99` for C99 with GNU extensions
- `-std=gnu11` for C11 with GNU extensions

Comment: Might I ask you further question? I searched internet and found `GNU 5.3.0` is default to `-std=gnu11`, but I still **have to** move all variable declarations to the beginning of the `main()` function, which is annoying, or I will get compiler error(on the Online Judge site UVa online judge, again), why?

Comment: @Rainning If this compiler is always using `-ansi`, that's the same as `-std=c89`.

Answer (score 4):

> How can I know which C standard(C89, C99, C11, C17/18) it adopted

`-ansi` doesn't mean "give me standard C". It means "give me dinosaur C" and is 100% equivalent to using `-std=c89`. So if you compiled with `-ansi`, you are using C89, period.

If you don't use `-ansi` or `-std=...` options, then gcc defaults to these versions:

- gcc before version 5.0.0 defaults to gnu90.
- gcc between version 5.0.0 and up to < 8.0.0 defaults to gnu11.
- gcc from 8.0.0 defaults to gnu17.

"gnu" being the C standard + non-standard extensions, in the above cases corresponding to C90, C11 and C17 respectively.

"gnu" mode is not strictly following the standard. In order to do that, you must compile with `-std=cxx` where xx is your desired version of C. This restricts gcc to a subset only containing standard C features.

But in order to actually make it strict when it comes to reporting compiler errors for invalid use of C, you must do `-std=cxx -pedantic-errors`.

Comment: I just read your great answer about the history of C standards this afternoon after I've posted this question, very happy to see your answer here.

Comment: @Rainning Okay well that one probably covers most of the above. I just wanted to add to dbush's answer that `-pedantic` is what actually makes gcc strict, `-std=cxx` alone isn't enough.